# Why am I getting an error calling this readFile method?

Tags: java

I'm getting an error using the method `readFile` which I used in the class `RunProgram`.

The error I'm getting is:

> RunProgram.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

The code of my `RunProgram` class is:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class RunProgram{        
  public static void main(String [] args){

    String [] namen = Input.geefInputNamen();

    ArrayList<Spelers> spelerDatabase = new ArrayList<Spelers>();
    spelerDatabase = FileReader.readFile("Player Database");    
   }
 }
```

The method `readFile` is defined in the code below:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class FileReader {

  public static ArrayList readFile(String naamvdfile) {
    ArrayList<Spelers> spelerDatabase = new ArrayList<Spelers>();   
   try {
int LineNr = 4;         
File aFile = new File (naamvdfile+ ".xlsx");
    BufferedReader aBr = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(aFile));                    
 String aLine ="";  
    while (aLine !=> null) {
            aLine = aBr.readLine();
            if (aLine != null) {
                String [] lineParts = aLine.split(";", -1);
                if (lineParts.length == 10) {

                    int overall = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[1]);
                    int shootMid = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[4]);
                    int shootDis = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[5]);
                    int defence = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[6]);
                    int rebounden = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[7]);
                    int playmaker = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[8]);
                    int atletisch = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[9]);

                    Spelers speler = new Spelers(lineParts[0], overall, 
                       lineParts[2], lineParts[3], shootMid, shootDis, 
                       defence, rebounden, playmaker, atletisch);
                    spelerDatabase.add(speler);
                }
                else System.out.println("Lijn " + LineNr +" is niet volledig 
                                       ingevuld!");
                LineNr++;
            }       
    }           
  System.out.println("Aantal spelers dat we inlazen: " + LineNr); 
   }        
 catch (Exception e) { }        
 return spelerDatabase;     
    } 
  }
```

This last code doesn't give an error while compiling.

Comment: what is the issue then?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is invalid Java: `while (aLine !=> null)`. You probably wanted to write `while (aLine != null)`

Comment: yeah you are right, but in my code it is correct, while uploading it to the forum I accidently added an > to it :)

Comment: I also think you will have an issue with the filename parameter when it contains a space, maybe calling it with quotes is better "\"Player Database\""

Comment: Related: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

You get an unchecked warning because `readFile()` returns an `ArrayList` while you save it to an object of type `ArrayList<Spelers>`. Simply change the return type of the method.

```
public static ArrayList<Spelers> readFile(String naamvdfile) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: i don't get it, do i need to change my return type to ArrayList<Spelers>? Anyway, the things works now :)

Comment: Correct. The name for what you were using was a "raw type". By omitting the generic type witness you also removed (albeit temporarily) a lot of the type safety surrounding the List.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function return type to `ArrayList<Spelers>` in the below function in `FileReader` class :

```
  public static ArrayList<Spelers> readFile(String naamvdfile) {
    ...
```

The `RunProgram` class is expecting an `ArrayList<Spelers>` whereas the method signature tells it that the return type is an untyped `ArrayList`.